# CRM 2013 : Customization migration tool

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I am working on CRM 2013 and want to migrate the javascript,UI changes done on one copy of CRM 2013 to another copy of CRM 2013.Both databases of CRM 2013 are of same organizations(means having exact same structure) only difference is one contains latest clients data.

Is there any good tool which can automate this process?

Thanks

Comment: It does not look like you did much research before asking this question. Solutions have been around since CRM 2011 was released over three years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you want to use standard approach called solutions?
To migrate changes you can create Solution, add changed components into it, export solution from source system and then import this solution to target system.